# Android - changing the design of ParseQueryAdapter pagination button

Tags: android, parse-platform

[Parse](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html) provides a ParseQueryAdapter and by default it has a built-in pagination feature.

```
setPaginationEnabled(boolean paginationEnabled);
```

The paginations design by default looks like this:

[image]

I wonder how I can create my own custom design for this on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what they say on their documentation, you have to override the method:

```
@Override
public View getNextPageView(View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        // R.layout.adapter_next_page contains an ImageView with a custom graphic
        // and a TextView.
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.adapter_next_page, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nextPageTextViewId);
    textView.setText("Loaded " + getCount() + " rows. Get more!");
    return v;
}
```